# T-SQL syntax abbreviation when JOIN columns have same name in both tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, syntax

In T-SQL, can a `JOIN` specification (`ON …`) possibly be simplified for an equi-join between two tables when such a join happens on two columns that have the same name in both tables?

```
CREATE TABLE T1 (X … PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE T2 (X … REFERENCES T1 (X));
```

Usually I would write such a (inner) join as follows:

```
SELECT … FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.X = T2.X;
```

What I would like is something simpler, such as:

```
SELECT … FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON X;
```

Is such an abbreviation of the `ON …` specification possible somehow? (I expect the answer will be "no", but I would like to make sure.)

If not, are there any particular reasons why not? (For instance, would it be likely to lead to frequent column ambiguities when more than two tables are joined, and therefore be of little practical use?)

Comment: Nope, type it out. You only type the query once. Anyway, some tools can even make that faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [natural join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join) in the ANSI 92 SQL standard

```
SELECT … FROM T1 NATURAL JOIN T2
```

However, this is not supported in SQL Server. Probably a good thing as there could be ambiguities when you do not specify joined columns explicity.

There is no abbreviation like the syntax you mentioned

```
    FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON X;
```

Comment: RE: ambiguities simply adding a new column to one of the joined tables later that happens to have the same name (and type?) of an existing column in the other table [would break things](http://gplivna.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/natural-joins-are-evil-motto-if-you.html). MySQL has `using`. Which is somewhat safer and more explicit.

Comment: Absolutely, for example you could have a customers table and an orders table, and expect them to both join on 'customerID', but if they both also have a 'status' field it will try to join on both columns

Comment: @JamieA: Wouldn't a smart RDBMS only perform joins on columns that partake in a (explicitly defined) foreign key relationship? If both tables had a `CustomerID` and a `Status` field, and both columns were linked through FK constraints, then a `NATURAL JOIN` would indeed be ambiguous -- but such an RDBMS could warn you about it and refuse to perform the join.

Comment: @JamieA: (cont'd:) If such an RDBMS supported schema binding, it could even refuse to create a 2nd FK constraint between two tables if there are, for instance, pre-existing views that perform a natural join between these tables. That would force you to first replace the view's natural join with a more explicit one before you could create the 2nd FK relationship. My conclusion: If natural joins required a "join template" in the form of an FK constraint, it seems that there wouldn't be any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

- In SQL Server (T-SQL), there's no such shortcut. You have to type out all the `JOIN` columns.
- In Oracle (P-SQL), `NATURAL JOIN` will match columns with the same name in both tables.
- In MySQL, `USING` is somewhat between SQL Server and Oracle in terms of verbosity. You only have to write the column names once `A JOIN B USING (col1, col2, col3)`

`NATURAL JOIN` is in ANSI SQL, but as we know, none of the major SQL vendors fully support the standard. Each has their own additions and deviations from the standard.